# Certificate / SSL connection problem in docker build on macOS

Tags: docker, docker-compose, ssl-certificate, dockerfile, docker-registry

I am building a docker image on **macOS**. This is the part of my Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04

# Dir you need to override to keep data on reboot/new container:
VOLUME /var/lib/mysql
#VOLUME /var/www/MISP/Config

# Dir you might want to override in order to have custom ssl certs
# Need: "misp.key" and "misp.crt"
#VOLUME /etc/ssl/private

# 80/443 - MISP web server, 3306 - mysql, 6379 - redis, 50000 - MISP ZeroMQ
EXPOSE 80 443 3306 6379 50000

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive
ENV DEBIAN_PRIORITY critical
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y supervisor cron logrotate syslog-ng-core postfix curl gcc git gnupg-agent make python3 openssl redis-server sudo vim zip wget mariadb-client mariadb-server sqlite3 moreutils apache2 apache2-doc apache2-utils libapache2-mod-php php php-cli php-gnupg php-dev php-json php-mysql php7.2-opcache php-readline php-redis php-xml php-mbstring rng-tools python3-dev python3-pip python3-yara python3-redis python3-zmq libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev zlib1g-dev python3-setuptools libpq5 libjpeg-dev libfuzzy-dev ruby asciidoctor tesseract-ocr imagemagick libpoppler-cpp-dev



RUN mkdir -p /var/www/MISP /root/.config /root/.git


WORKDIR /var/www/MISP
RUN chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/MISP /root/.config /root/.git
RUN sudo -u www-data -H git clone https://github.com/MISP/MISP.git /var/www/MISP
```

When I build the image, it returns this error:

```
Step 16/16 : RUN sudo -u www-data -H git clone https://github.com/MISP/MISP.git /var/www/MISP
 ---> Running in f0f0b76b353c
Cloning into '/var/www/MISP'...
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/MISP/MISP.git/': server certificate verification failed. CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt CRLfile: none
```

It can't find the certificate. Even if I add `RUN git config --global http.sslverify "false"` it passes this error but it returns error in the rest of the Dockerfile.

It means that my Docker for macOS has problem with ssl connections, is there any configuration for ssl certificates or other ssl setting for Docker in **mac** that I missed?

Comment: Building your docker file on my macOS machine doesn't reproduce the issue you describe; the clone works fine for me with a standard docker install.

Comment: thanks, for me, it's not cloning from git.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have run into the same issue. Exactly the same error message.

What you have to realize here is that the `git` command you are running is inside the `docker` environment and has nothing to do with the fact that you are on `MacOS`, or the `git` version you have installed in your operating system.

What is happening here is that the plain `ubuntu:18.04` image is outdated and doesn't have up to date certificates.

In my case I fixed this by adding the following two statements right after you `FROM` line:

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04

# Update the OS
RUN apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y
```

In my case it was another base image but the behavior/solution was the same.